# Is it better to do convert builder provided carpet stairs to hardwood yourself, or have the builder do it from the start (e.g. for townhome)?

Tags: stairs, carpet, hardwood, new-home

Title should summarize the question. I have heard that in general it is good to have certain troublesome things done by your builder from the start, depending on factors like

- lest you have to damage your own foundation
- go to large amounts of trouble to tear things down to do them. (I'm not sure nor do I remember what kinds of changes these are).
- complexity
- cost

I am curious what the opinions are about carpet vs hardwood stairs.

Unrelatedly I don't have the reputation to create a townhome tag if it would be relevant/good to do so.

Comment: I don't see any reason why what you're asking about would be different for a townhouse vs a free standing one, so no need for a new tag.

Comment: If you're having a new house built (no matter the format of the house), it should be up to you to determine whether the stairs are bare hardwood or are carpeted. Make your decision and have the builder do it as part of the construction process. If you change your mind a few years down the road, you can then decide to make the adjustment yourself or hire it out.

Answer (score 1):

If the builder is giving you the option and he has the material, I'd go for it. After all the work is done, the last thing you want to do is rip out the stairs and put in new ones. Carpet on stairs takes a beating especially on the edge and vacuuming them is a pain. Sure, it will cost more (much more) than a DIY project but it will be money well spent.

Answer (score 1):

Let the builder do it, carpet may hide some flaw that may require greater effort for somebody who comes along later.